# How to get the data within the same day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a query to calculate the verified order within the same day. Regarding how to calculate, I can do it but to limit the time, can you help me?

For example: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, enddate, startdate) <= '24'`,
the time will be within 1 day, but it can be from one day to next day.
Then how can get the data within the same day?
My original query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
1.0 * count(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `Created Datetime`, `Order Verification Date`) <= '2' THEN `BOB Sales Order Item` ELSE NULL END) / COUNT(`BOB Sales Order Item`) AS within_2hours_rate,
1.0 * count(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `Created Datetime`, `Order Verification Date`) <= '24' THEN `BOB Sales Order Item` ELSE NULL END) / COUNT(`BOB Sales Order Item`) AS within_the_sameday_rate
FROM data.oms
WHERE `Created Datetime` BETWEEN '2017-10-29 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-04 23:59:59' AND `Order Verification Status` = 'finance_verified'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any date column as well in your db so u can identify or differentiate from it.

Comment: yes, I need to calculate the verified order within the same day

Comment: please describe table structure so we can find out the date column and filter on it.

Comment: and my original query is 
SELECT COUNT(*)
  ,
1.0 * count(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `Created Datetime`, `Order Verification Date`) <= '24' THEN `BOB Sales Order Item` ELSE NULL END) / COUNT(`BOB Sales Order Item`) AS within_the_sameday_rate
 
  FROM data.oms
  WHERE `Created Datetime` BETWEEN '2017-10-29 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-04 23:59:59' AND `Order Verification Status` = 'finance_verified'

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to check that the two times are on the same calendar day then you can do `` DATE(`Created Datetime`) = DATE(`Order Verification Date`) ``.

Comment: SO I just need to add this condition to the WHERE in my original query, right?

Comment: Yes, in place of the second `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, I believe.